# Series: Female half-demon/half-angel paranormal P.I. sends demons back to hell

Tags: story-identification, demons

Almost five years ago, I downloaded a free book onto my Kindle. It was about a female half-demon, half-angel protagonist who was like a paranormal P.I., sending demons back to hell. She had a demon partner, a demon lover, her guardian angel (who was later revealed to be her aunt) and her friend, a human cop. Her father was in the highest choir of angels and her mother was demon royalty as was her lover and her partner.

I cannot remember the name of the series or the author, or even the name of the female protagonist, and I no longer have access to that Kindle.

Does anyone know of how I can find this series again?

Comment: Can't you log into your Amazon account and see what books you have in your account?

Comment: Eh... I'd say *Agent of Hel*, but that has no angel(s) in it.  Matches the rest, kinda, depending on how you define "demon".

Comment: My husband had set up that kindle as a surprise birthday present, then he forgot all the info. the kindle was crushed by my toddler. I have a new kindle now, with all my info and set up by me, but there are over 400 books on the old on I can't access. This is the series I really want though.

Comment: *Hellsbane* has a half-angel inspector who sends demons back to hell,  but there's no mention of a demonic partner and her other half is human.

Comment: You are certainly not the first person to forget info for a Kindle. I echo the advice already given. Your best bet is to contact Amazon support and explain your situation.

Comment: One of these, probably: [Nephilim in popular culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephilim_in_popular_culture#Popular_fiction)

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/The-Fire-Within-Nephilim-Book-ebook/dp/B00I15VKKA

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/16186.Nephilim_Novels

Answer (score 6):

This is the [Bedeviled and Beyond series by Sam Cheever](https://web.archive.org/web/20170424023600/http://www.samcheever.com/series.html#bedeviledbeyond).

1. Bedeviled & Beguiled
2. Bedeviled & Bedazzled
3. Bedeviled & Beleaguered
4. Bedeviled & Belittled
5. Bedeviled & Besmirched
6. Bedeviled & Befouled
7. Bedeviled & Bah Humbug
8. Beset & Bewildered

The heroine of books 1-7 is Astra Phelps:

> What exactly is a halfling you ask? A halfling is a non-human. They have neither wings nor horns, but generally have both angel and devil in their family forests. Which is probably why they enjoy a higher sensitivity to spectral influence than regular human people.
>
> My name is Astra Q. Phelps and I’m a halfling. Don’t ask me what the Q stands for because that little piece of info will go with me to the crematorium. I’ve had all printed documentation of the name destroyed and though a lot of my enemies have tried to dig it out, no one will ever know what it stands for. A girl has to have some secrets. Especially when the truth would cause her some serious embarrassment.
>
> I run a business called the Angel Network, which is the only devil and demon locating and destroying business in the universe. In other words, I kick serious evil butt for a living. I am a halfling. But I digress. You were interested in my story weren’t you? Well here we go.

Comment: Hi Amanda. Your answer got downvoted I suspect because we generally like answers to explain why the books match the question. Since I have the first book I've extended your answer with some extra info from the book.