# Book series about a female detective partnered with a part-human, part-demon, male cop

Tags: story-identification, books, demons, detective

Read this series around about 2008-2010; thought they were either by Rachel Caine or Kelley Armstrong, but from what I can see I must be mistaken.

From what I can remember of the concept, humans and demons had agreed to allow demons to share the body of humans. Our female lead keeps a strict control over her inner demon, not trusting that it won't try and take full control over her. Her partner (who for some reasons I think is called John, but I may well be misremembering that part) openly shares his body/soul with his demon, and thus whilst he acts in a normal human fashion, it's always the demon part of her partner that has conversations with the female lead.

The hosting of demons within humans was negotiated between the governments of the humans and hell and thus was not a secret agreement, and humans volunteered to be hosts. Cannot remember why our female lead became a host given her will to remain in control of the demon inside her, but on occasion she did allow her demon to take control, under strict conditions.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120612/series-female-half-demon-half-angel-paranormal-p-i-sends-demons-back-to-hell?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what was the detective's name? What did she look like? How old was she? Why did humans agree to share their bodies with demons? Did these demons physically manifest in some way? Was this an adult book (with sex/erotica/violence/gore) or something for young adults? Did the demons have names? Why didn't she share her body with her demon? Did her demon talk to her? What was she *detecting* (Crime? PI work?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_with_the_Dead_(novel)?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Living with the Dead](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2813124-living-with-the-dead)* by Kelley Armstrong?

Key characters include Hope Adams, a half-demon reporter and John Finnley, a necromancer homicide detective.

> It's been six months since Robyn's husband Damon died. Since then,
> she's moved to LA to start a new life for herself. She's a PR rep for
> a celebutante, but she's really just going through the motions. Hope
> is worried about her --the two are longtime friends-- so she and Karl
> come to visit. Shortly after they arrive, Robyn's client is killed and
> thanks to a string of unlikely events, Robyn becomes the prime
> suspect. Then Karl and Hope must figure out who really killed the
> woman and why, while protecting Robyn from the real killer.
>
> Investigating the case is Detective John Finnley. Finn's a
> necromancer, though he doesn't even really know what that means. He
> only knows that he occasionally sees ghosts... a skill that helps him
> believe Robyn is innocent, not only of her client's murder but other
> deaths that are piling up in her wake. The ghosts of the victims help
> lead his way, and so does (eventually) the ghost of Robyn's husband.

Comment: Thanks but I'd checked that one already. The two main characters were both detectives and were hosts to demons. The hosting of demons within humans had been negotiated between the two respective governments of Earth and Hell. The female lead kept a very tight control on her demon, whilst the male character openly allowed his demon to take control when required, and was constantly trying to persuade the female lead to allow the demon inside her more freedom. With it being over 15 years ago since I read the book specific details are hard to recall.